# What is meant by a component has one or more implementation?

Tags: components

The component must be supported by one or more implementations. The implementer may choose any implementation approach deemed to be suitable. The only constraint is on meeting the behavior defined in the specification. In many cases, this flexibility includes the choice of programming language used to develop the component implementation

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what you are looking for is explained here with respect to java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface?rq=1